# Is it possible to switch between WiFi and 3G in my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, twitter, wifi

I am working on an iOS app that gets connected to a local WiFi network without Internet access.

In the main screen of my app I want to show the option to post a message in Twitter or Facebook.

Is it possible to switch to a 3G connection to send the tweet or delay the message until there is an active Internet connection ??

Thanks!

Comment: No. Finally what I do is capture the Facebook message or tweet with REComposeViewController (https://github.com/romaonthego/REComposeViewController)

Answer (score 1):

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
}
```

it's differentiate the network status.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to check if I am connected through 3G or WiFi. What I really want is to force to connect with 3G when I am in a WiFi network.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apple Reachability library: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to check if I am connected through 3G or WiFi. What I really want is to force to connect with 3G when I am in a WiFi network

Comment: You'll have to delay the message. Unlike Android, iOS doesn't allow apps to mess with the WiFi connection.